# How to convert string into unicode in Python3?

Tags: python, decode

I tried a lot of ways to convert the string like b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x99\x85\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe8\xb0\x8a' into Chinese characters but all failed.

It's really strange that when I just use

> print(b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x99\x85\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe8\xb0\x8a')

It will show decoded Chinese Characters.

But if I got the string by reading from my CSV file, it won't do. No matter how I decode the string, it will only show me b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x99\x85\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe8\xb0\x8a'

Here is my script:

```
import csv 

with open('need_convert.csv','r+') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:

        new_row=''.join(row)
        print('new_row:')
        print(type(new_row))
        print(new_row)

        print('convert:')
        print(new_row.decode('utf-8'))
```

Here is my data (csv file):
b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x99\x85\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe8\xb0\x8a'
b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe9\xba\x92\xe9\xba\x9f\xe6\x9d\xaf'
b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x99\x85\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe8\xb0\x8a'

Comment: Do not post code/data as images.  Post as text

Comment: have you tried:  `print(str(your_encoding))`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include the Python-code as text and include a also some more examples of coded characters in text-form. Thanks!

Comment: You need to read with the correct encoding.

Comment: Hi Fallenreaper, Yes, I've tried you method, not working. Sorry.

Comment: The lines are bring read in as strings, not bytes.

Comment: If that's really what the file looks like when you open it in an editor, then whoever wrote out the file messed up bad. It's going to be painful to restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` contents and `new_row` are both strings, not byte types. Below, I'm using `exec('s=' + row[0])` to interpret them as desired, assuming the input is safe.

```
import csv

with open('need_convert.csv','r+') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(type(row[0]), row[0])
        exec('s=' + row[0])
        print(type(s), s)
        print(s.decode('utf-8'))
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'> b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x99\x85\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe8\xb0\x8a'
<class 'bytes'> b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x99\x85\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe8\xb0\x8a'
国际友谊
<class 'str'> b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe9\xba\x92\xe9\xba\x9f\xe6\x9d\xaf'
<class 'bytes'> b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe9\xba\x92\xe9\xba\x9f\xe6\x9d\xaf'
麒麟杯
<class 'str'> b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x99\x85\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe8\xb0\x8a'
<class 'bytes'> b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe9\x99\x85\xe5\x8f\x8b\xe8\xb0\x8a'
国际友谊
```

Comment: What does one do when they do not trust the input?